# Fonts seem pixelated on a new 3567 Dell laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, fonts

I bought a new [Dell Inspiron 15" 3567](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/new-inspiron-15-3000/spd/inspiron-15-3567-laptop) with an Intel HD graphics 520. I am running Windows 10 Home 1703 with the recommanded resolution (1366x768px). I tried without Cleartype and with, I went through the cleartype wizard a few times choosing from different samples. The display adapter seems to be properly installed, yet fonts still appear pixelated, accross the system. Is there a way to fix it?

- Is it DPI related and is there nothing to do?
- Can a different driver make a difference?
- Can a different OS version make a difference?

My last laptop was [Inpiron 3521](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/cty/pdp/spd/inspiron-15-3521) running Windows 8 and the fonts seemed clear. Attached is a screenshot of the current model's screen:

[image: sample screenshot]

Comment: Can you check to see if font smoothing (anti aliasing) is turned on? If you press Win + R and enter `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` then click the **Settings...** button within the **Performance** section, **Smooth edges of screen fonts** should be checked

Comment: @JamesP Followed your instructions and turned on cleartype again which improved the condition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DYs4.png
Now it seems it is less blurry but still there is pixalation and the font appears to be without depths.

Comment: Do you have DPI scaling set to more than 100%?

Comment: Also, a 1366 x 768 15” screen will always look pixelated at close distances unfortunately. Your second screenshot looks fairly normal.

Comment: Step back a little. Ok, good, now a little more. There. Now how does it look? :)

Comment: @JamesP, not really, it seems something is off with Dell's displays (some manufacturers - I've heard) , I have Samsung laptop and 1366*768 is completely different. The OP should return it to store (if possible) and ask for money or better laptop if the device will be used as a workstation. P.S. I have Dell with the same pixelated sh*t fonts all over the place.